# How do I add HTML files to a GitHub repo?

Tags: javascript, html, css, github

I have a HTML file, along with some JS and CSS files, in a project I have been working on, and am trying to put them onto my GitHub account. I created a new repo, but when I tried to add the files (some are in folders), I didn't know how to. The website isn't very helpful and I'm really stuck. Could anyone tell me how to upload them? I'm new to GitHub and so far very confused by it.

Thanks a lot in advance xx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using windows, try [github for windows](http://windows.github.com/) application. It's easy way to start using github if you are new to it.

Comment: sorry to be a bother, but what does the 'commit' stuff mean?

Comment: You seem to be really new to version control systems. I suggest you to do this http://www.codeschool.com/courses/try-git -tutorial, which explains the core concept of git really well.